# Sufficient condition for martingale property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0},\mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space and $M=(M_t)_{t\geq 0}$ an $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted stochastic process. If
$$ \forall t<s, \ \mathbb{E}[M_s|\mathcal{F}_t]=M_t $$
$M$ is said to be a martingale. Now let assume I can integrate with respect to $M$ (say $M$ is a semi-martingale and I am using Itô integration). Then
$$ \forall t < s, \ \mathbb{E}[\int_t^s dM_u | F_t] = 0 $$
still implies that $M$ is a martingale. What about
$$ \forall t < s, \ \mathbb{E}[\int_t^s \alpha_u dM_u | F_t] = 0 $$
where $\alpha$ is a predictable stochastic process ? Under which conditions on $\alpha$ (except being constant) is $M$ still a martingale ?

Comment: You shouldn't use the variable "$s$" both as an limit of integration and as a variable of integration: $$\int_s^t dM_s.$$

Comment: Oh sure my bad. Edited.

Comment: (I have removed my answer because it requires that $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a *continuous* semimartingale.)

Comment: If you are still willing to answer look at $M_t := \sup_{u<t}W_u$ where $W$ is a Brownian motion. It is a continuous finite variation process (since increasing) hence not a martingale and seem to cancel the integral almost everywhere. This is just an intuition though, did not prove anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel the integral almost everywhere"?

Comment: I just mean that $M$ is constant most of the time (straightforward by looking at a plot, again no rigorous proof here just intuition) so integrating w.r.t. $M$ should yield something close to zero.